# Validating schema using attribute

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd, schema

I have the following xml:

```
<Root>
    <SomethingA/>
    <SomethingB/>
    <SomethingC/>
    <SomeOtherThing action="Foo">
        <Bar/>
        <Bar/>
    </SomeOtherThing>
    <SomeOtherThing action="Poo">
        <BarFoo/>
        <BarNoo/>
    </SomeOtherThing>
</Root>
```

I want to create a schema, that will validate that if the element is SomeOtherThing, then if the action is Foo the child element can only be Bar; if the action is Poo then the child elements can be BarFoo (and/or) BarNoo.

Any ideas on how it can be accomplish (using only xsd)?

Also, the solution need to work on C#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you validate Elements based on an attribute Value using a Schema?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184663/how-can-you-validate-elements-based-on-an-attribute-value-using-a-schema)

Comment: update the question. i only care about xsd validation solutions. but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of conditional validation cannot be done in XSD 1.0. It can be done in XSD 1.1 using the feature called "conditional type assignment".

Comment: Is there a way to use XSD 1.1 in Visual Studio? (2010/2012) everywhere i look i see that there is no support for it (edit the question)

Comment: XSD 1.1 is currently supported in Saxon (9.4) and Apache Xerces (beta). I'm aware of other unannounced processors in development (but not from Microsoft). Microsoft no longer seem to be interested in keeping their XML products up to date with W3C standards.